# Protect a file with a password, but transparently integrated in Windows's UI

Tags: windows-7, encryption, passwords, text-editors

I know there are several solutions to:

- encrypt a file: zipping/RARing/7zip-ing **with password** each time we save, unzipping/unraring/un7ziping and entering password each time we want to open the file
- encrypt a partition: Bitlocker (which I already do use), VeraCrypt/Truecrypt

Here I'm looking for something else: imagine you have a `personalnotes.txt` file.

I'd like that each time I double-click on it (i.e. opening it with my favorite text editor such as Notepad++ or Sublime), it **first** prompts for a password, and open the text editor then.
And each time I do save (CTRL+S in the text editor), it saves without asking (with or without asking, I don't mind).

I'm looking for something totally **transparently integrated** in Windows 7, i.e. I don't want to have to run a batch file each time I read/write the file. Also I don't want to have to launch a plugin in the text editor each time I open the file.

Is there a file encryption solution that could be transparently integrated in Windows 7 / filesystem (without having to run a third party tool automatically).

Note: I've already tried EFS encryption but if I want that the file is not available without password after a reboot, I would have to remove / reenable the keys/certificates each time, so EFS is not an option. (too heavy to remove the certificates each time I want to close the file).

Note: I'm not asking for a 3rd party tool recommendation, I wanted to know if this is doable with standard Windows 7 internal tools.

Comment: What's wrong with a very small TC/VeraCrypt container? Or how about a separate program with it's own encrypted file format, like KeePass, only more for notes, if desired?

Comment: Note: I'm not asking for a 3rd party tool recommendation, I wanted to know if this is doable with standard Windows 7 internal tools.

Comment: For mods/people who suggest to close: please consider my previous comment, I was looking for an internal Windows solution.

Answer (score 3):

Using the built-in tools for Windows this isn't possible given the constraints you have stipulated.

You COULD write a batch script that takes the currently selected file(s) and creates a password protected zip file. You'd probably have to use the command-line version of 7zip to package this.

Place a shortcut to this batch file in the Send To menu folder and then you'd be able to right-click on files and send them to a password-protected zip file.

BUT...

If you wanted to access the files you'd have to decompress them, work on them, and then re-compress them again.

The thing is, it appears to me you're trying to solve a problem people have already solved using a utility people have not yet invented in the very specific and narrow confines of what you'd prefer to do.

There are already good encryption utilities, both for entire file systems and for individual files, but they don't behave the way you describe because that is simply not possible. In order for Notepad++ to silently save to a password protected file it would have to be able to write natively to that file, via a cached password or some other unknown integration. And if you wanted anything besides Notepad++ to do this, that same integration would have to exist for that program too.

It's simply too big, too broad a problem, and it is big and broad because you have a very specific and narrow set of requirements.

If, instead, you were to explain WHY you wanted to do things this way, laying out a clear scenario, it is POSSIBLE that we could suggest an alternative that meets your needs that you have not yet considered or are not aware of.